# SSRProvider info messages when build project

Tags: next.js

When I npm run build my next.js project I have this info (When server rendering, you must wrap your application in an  to ensure consistent ids are generated between the client and server.)

What should I do with this messages?

This is my _app.tsx

```
import {SSRProvider} from '@react-aria/ssr';

 <SSRProvider>
      <div className={inter.className}>
          <Head>
              <title>Next js news app</title>
              <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript" />
              <meta name="description" content="Next js news" />
          </Head>
          <NextNProgress />
          <NavBar />

              <Container className={styles.pageContainer}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
              </Container>
      </div>
      </SSRProvider>
```